# Azure DevOps - incorrect email when user is logging in, added through AAD

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

First time here, but many days a lurker.

I've experienced a problem that I've not managed to solve yet within my company.
We recently added a new user to our DevOps (it's done through groups in AAD), the groups are fine and have worked with users earlier.
We've not done any real changes to the AAD or DevOps as of late that should affect the sync.

So I added the groups we use to the user, they should now have access to the repositories, just like their colleagues.

But nope, they get an infinite loading when trying to access our dev.azure.com/companyname - they get a mail etc.

The first time I added them to the groups, they showed up as "direct" rather than "group rule", so I got rid of them and readded them, now it says "group rule". But the email is not correct (it was also incorrect the first time around).

They did try and reach it with the correct email.
I'm believing that the issue is due to this odd email that is not the same as everyone elses in DevOps.
Their colleagues that it works for all have the same setup on their AAD accounts.

Anyone have seen this before?

We've tried incognito mode, we've tried to https://aka.ms/vssignout in incognito etc.
As well as the above mentioned remove and re-add, which at least made it be set to "group rule".

We've tried incognito mode, we've tried to https://aka.ms/vssignout in incognito etc.
As well as the above mentioned remove and re-add, which at least made it be set to "group rule".

Expected the email to be set to the correct one, and that they can get passed the infinite loading when trying to access dev.azure.com/companyname

Comment: Hi, please check whether the AAD Group is added as 'Stakeholder' access level to your org, if so, change it to 'Basic' access level. And also navigate to Project Settings -> Repositories -> "the specified repo" -> Security to see whether the "Read" permission is 'Deny' to the AAD Group. If so, change 'Deny' to 'Allow' to the AAD Group.

After checking the info above, then you could try turning off the setting "Limit user visibility and collaboration to specific projects" via checking in "Preview features", then try clearing the cache and re-adding the AAD Group to see if it works.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your reply.
I checked all the permissions, and they're correct, all set to "Allow" etc.
I was curious and decided to create a new account and try it with, same groups and such. And it worked fine.

Comment: Hi @DavidEldritch if you solved your issue kindly post as an answer so that it will be helpful for other members who can encounter the same problem.

Comment: Hi, sorry, should have specified that the issue with the users account is still an issue. I've yet to remake their account, as that would be a lengthy process in itself. So I'd like to avoid it. But may not have an option to, as I've yet to find a good way to solve it without doing such.

Comment: We found the solution.
Most likely a cache thing, very strange.
We removed all Azure groups from the user connected to DevOps, then we removed the user from DevOps, re-eval rules, waited 24h, added again, and this time it worked as it should have from the start.

So most likely some form of cache issue. As all that was tried before, just not the wait 24h part.